# Поле FileField в админке. Открыть ссылку в новом окне

Tags: django

Есть поле
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на ссылку открывается в текущем окне, нужно в новом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью CSS это сделать на сколько я понимаю не реально, поэтому придется пилить админку:

> Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/widgets/clearable_file_input.html

```
...
<a href="{{ widget.value.url }}" target="_blank">{{ widget.value }}</a>
...
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!